# How do I solve CORS issues in Apollo, Node, and Next.js?

Tags: node.js, graphql, next.js, react-apollo, prisma

I need help troubleshooting I CORS error I am having in Apollo, Node, and Next.js.  I am not sure what change I have made, but suddenly I am unable to fetch the data from my Prisma database.  I am currently running dev mode.  My Yoga server which pulls in my data from Prisma run at localhost:4444.  My frontend is run on localhost:7777.

Here is my CORS setup:

```js
import withApollo from "next-with-apollo";
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
import { endpoint, prodEndpoint } from "../config";
import { LOCAL_STATE_QUERY } from "../components/Cart";

function createClient({ headers }) {
  return new ApolloClient({
    uri: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? endpoint : prodEndpoint,
    request: (operation) => {
      operation.setContext({
        fetchOptions: {
          credentials: "include",
        },
        headers,
      });
    },
    // local data
    clientState: {
      resolvers: {
        Mutation: {
          toggleCart(_, variables, { cache }) {
            // read the cartOpen value from the cache
            const { cartOpen } = cache.readQuery({
              query: LOCAL_STATE_QUERY,
            });
            // Write the cart State to the opposite
            const data = {
              data: { cartOpen: !cartOpen },
            };
            cache.writeData(data);
            return data;
          },
        },
      },
      defaults: {
        cartOpen: false,
      },
    },
  });
}

export default withApollo(createClient);
```

variables.env

```
FRONTEND_URL="localhost:7777"
PRISMA_ENDPOINT="https://us1.prisma.sh/tim-smith-131869/vouch4vet_dev_backend/dev"
PRISMA_SECRET="..."
APP_SECRET="..."
STRIPE_SECRET="..."
PORT=4444
```

backend index.js

```js
const server = createServer();

server.express.use(cookieParser());

// decode the JWT so we can get the user Id on each request
server.express.use((req, res, next) => {
  const { token } = req.cookies;
  if (token) {
    const { userId } = jwt.verify(token, process.env.APP_SECRET);
    // put the userId onto the req for future requests to access
    req.userId = userId;
  }
  next();
});
```

I have tried rolling back to previous commit and I have had no luck.  I have not ruled out internet problems.

Let me know if you need to see the rest of my repo.

Thanks

Comment: When are you getting CORS issues ? While accessing your localhost server app from local frontend app ?

Comment: Fes, from mt front end on :7777

Comment: Then you will need to provide CORS config in your Node js server. It is allowed / blocked on server side. You just need to allow / whitelist your front-end server url.